# Problem when trying to write XML in mac

Tags: php, xml

i've been having problems trying to write attributes of xml files using php in mac. Now, the weird thing is that it works flawlesly on windows, but when i try to run the script in a mac, for some mysterious reason beyond me, it keeps writing the atributes of the xml file with dashes, this is the actual xml file that the script writes:

```
<stuff id=\"stuffid\"></stuff>
```

this is php code, really basic script:

```
$file = fopen("data.xml","w");
      fwrite($file, $xml);
      fclose($file);
```

can anyone lend a hand?, i've been looking for a solution to this all morning, im using mamp by the way

Comment: Where does $xml come from? Show how it's constructed. I'm smelling misuse of the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant.

Comment: it comes from a SWF as XML, the code above all the code i have in the script, aside from the $_POST

Comment: So where is the error? Do you recieve the XML with /" or do those magically get added by fwrite()? What is written if you `fwrite($file, $_POST);`

Comment: yes that's the problem, they just get magically added, the XML doesnt have the /", but let me try what you sugest, it's so weird it's driving me crazy

Comment: Still nothinng, man this really is frustrating

Comment: Ok, so if $_POST already contains /" then either the flash app sends that or something is happening to $_POST before your script sees it. One cause would be auto_prepend_file ini setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the XML is coming from an external source as a string, my best guess is that php is mis-configured, in this case it's probably the magic_quotes_gpc setting, which should be set to "Off"

Comment: That did it!!, thank you very much. Man i was going crazy with this problem

Answer (score 1):

You probably have magic quotes turned on. Try this:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    $xml = stripcslashes($xml);
```

Learn more at http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: Thank you, clearly i need to read more about that, i'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using the [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class or [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) class to construct your document?

It'll handle all this stuff for you...